# submitting my own built bio stuck

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

When I tried to build a bio and use generic_make_request, I got flooded with this kind of messages.

The pseudocode is following

```
struct page *page = kmalloc(sizeof(struct page), GFP_KERNEL);
struct bio *bio = bio_alloc(GFP_KERNEL);
set_bio(bio);
add_bio_page(bio, page);
submit_bio(bio);
```

Then the log will be flooded with messages like:

```
nommu_map_sg overflow xxxxxxxxxxx+4096 of device mask ffffffff
```

When I change allocation of page to

```
struct page *page = alloc_page(GFP_KERNEL);
```

Kernel just hung up and I can see large CPU consumption of the VM I use.

Comment: **Exact** duplicate of [submit new struct bio to generic\_make\_request meets trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629125/submit-new-struct-bio-to-generic-make-request-meets-trouble)

Comment: @Olaf, yes.. I saw a [on hold] on that question, I'm afraid no one can see that...

Comment: ... and you thought trying once more without respecting the given reason or even adding the required information would be a good idea ...

Comment: @Olaf, I've added details to old question, but I'm afraid that it won't be seen so I post a new question here with the added details.

Comment: "detail" == added line break? Good joke! Who are you trying to fool?

Comment: @Olaf, I added the pseudocode. The original version of the old question is only asking what's the meaning of "nommu_map_sg...". I added the pseudocode which show how I got the messags.

Answer (score 0):

I can't point to the exact error, but your code lacks a few elements:

- the `bi_bdev` field of `struct bio` should point to a block device
- the `bi_end_io` field should point to an I/O completion routine

Comment: I've set them. I want to add one additional bio request inside do_blockdev_direct_IO, I don't know if it is the allocation of page that matters.